# Custom windows service error: Cannot start <servicename> service on computer '.'

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I wrote a custom Windows service to backup files between two network disks. I'm trying to run this service on a Windows server 2012. The service installes just fine, but when I try to start it it gives met this error: Cannot start  service on computer '.'. 
This is my code:

```
public partial class OptiekBackupService : ServiceBase
{
    private System.Threading.Timer aTimer;

    public OptiekBackupService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("OptiekBackupSource"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "OptiekBackupSource", "OptiekBackupLog");
        }
        EventLogger.Source = "OptiekBackupSource";
        EventLogger.Log = "OptiekBackupLog";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventLogger.WriteEntry("OptiekBackupService Started");
        double TimeOfExecution = 6;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime today5am = now.Date.AddHours(TimeOfExecution);
        DateTime next5am = now <= today5am ? today5am : today5am.AddDays(1);

        System.Threading.TimerCallback callback = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(RunBackup);

        this.aTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, next5am - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        //new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, next5am - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        EventLogger.WriteEntry("OptiekBackupService Stopped");
    }

    public void RunBackup(Object stateInfo)
    {
        EventLogger.WriteEntry("Backup started");
        RecursiveLookUp("X:\\", "W");
        RecursiveLookUp("Z:\\", "Y");
        EventLogger.WriteEntry("Backup completed");
    }
    //Recursieve methode om bestanden te doorlopen. 
    void RecursiveLookUp(string Loc, string Dest)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("We bevinden ons hier :" + Loc);
        /*if (Directory.GetDirectories(Loc).Length == 0)
        {
            CopyFiles(Loc, Dest);
            Console.WriteLine("Stop einde van filestructuur bereikt.");
        }
        else
        {*/
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Loc);
            foreach (var item in dirs)
            {
                RecursiveLookUp(item, Dest);
            }
            CopyFiles(Loc, Dest);
        //}
    }

    static void CopyFiles(string Loc, string Dest)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Loc);
        //Create directory hier
        string NewLocDir = Dest + Loc.Substring(1);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(NewLocDir);
        //Console.WriteLine(NewLoc);
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(item);
            string NewLocFile = Dest + item.Substring(1);
            if (File.Exists(NewLocFile))
            {
                if (File.GetLastWriteTime(NewLocFile) < File.GetLastWriteTime(item))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(NewLocFile);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(item, NewLocFile);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Copy to: " + NewLocFile + " Completed");
                }
                /*else
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("File is up to date no copy needed");
                }*/
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(item, NewLocFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use powershell to install and start.

When I try and start the service in de server manager it doesn't start as well so I doubt the problem is with this sript.

Maybe it's a setting somewhere I'm forgetting in the properties of my VS project?

I followed this: [MSDN Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you looked in event viewer?

Comment: Please show the code that actually throws the error.

Comment: What user are you running the service as? And does that user have admin permissions needed to create an event source?

Comment: I don't know where the error comes from. I've installed the service with nothing in it and it still doesn't want to run. I'm using the default Administrator account. The server is the Domain Controller.